# Does this function access and analyze an array properly?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I working on an assignment for my introduction to programming class which is meant to perform operations on an array of grades. Here are the details:

Usinging the following parallel arrays:

```
const int NUM_GRADES =5;
string Students[NUM_STUDENTS] = {"Tom","Jane","Jo"};
int grades[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_GRADES] ={{78,98,88,99,77},
                                       {62,99,94,85,93},
                                       {73,82,88,85,78}};
```

Write a function called displayNumStudentsAtLeastBForSelectedAssignment that takes the student and grade arrays as parameters, allows the user to select a valid assignment and locates and displays the number of the student with at least a grade >= 80  for that assignment in the format in the sample run below.

Here is the code I have written for this function. I am wondering if my logic makes sense as I was working on this all night and have just found a *potential* solution

```
//Displays the number of students with at least a B (>=80)
int DisplayNumStudentsAtLeastBForSelectedAssignment(string Students[NUM_STUDENTS], int grades[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_GRADES])
{
    std::cout << "Number of students with atleast a B: " << endl;
    std::cout << "Please enter in an assignment number: ";
    int assignmentNum;
    std::cin >> assignmentNum;
    getValidAssignmentNumber(assignmentNum);

    int total =0;
    for (int x = 0; x < NUM_STUDENTS; x++)
    {
        if (grades[x][assignmentNum-1]>= 80)
            total = total + 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Number of students with at least B on assignment " << assignmentNum << ": " << total << endl;
}
```

The function seems to be working properly. Just curious if there is a more efficient way of doing it. Thank you all for the help in advance.

Comment: If you want help improving working code you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so please delete the question here.

Comment: Sorry @NathanOliver . I will remember that for the future!

Comment: As already stated, such question is better suited on CodeReview, but, we can't answer such a question either, due to it lacking [mre] (note: CodeReview alse require it).

Comment: I have removed excess code to make the problem in question more clear.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that `const` is a compile time constant. But that is necessary for array declaration. Use `constexpr`

Comment: Using all uppercase compile constants is anti-pattern, you better get rid of it.

Comment: the array and const ints were given as part of the assignment. For the sake of following directions I have to keep them how they are. @Slava

Comment: It is worse that they even teach that way and propagate bad behavior.

Comment: I was taught that variables in all caps are usually reserved for global constants. @Slava

Comment: @singergiant no, it is worse. There is a convinience to have preprocessor identifiers (and only them!) all uppercase as name collision with preprocessor is a disaster. That minimises your chances if you do not use them anywhere else. Coming from C constants used to be defined in preprocessor so it became a habbit. Now, when they are compiler identifiers this old habbit works completely opposite - you are increasing chance to have name collision with a preprocessor.